# Counting all rows in the table at given month, not only those added that month

Tags: mysql, count

It is very easy to count all rows added lets say in june 2011, simply by using

```
GROUP BY YEAR(record_date), MONTH(record_date)
```

But I wonder how to do that while counting the number of all rows in the table at given date - that would require also counting those added before.

for example adding 5 rows per month:
i would like to result look like this: 5, 10, 15 and so on during the month.

Comment: if you're only adding 5 rows per month, your count will only be 5 for any given month.  Are you looking for a running total?

Comment: I don't get it, can you explain better? with examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SET @total = 0;
SELECT
  Year,
  Month,
  new,
  @total := @total + new AS Total 
FROM (
  SELECT
    YEAR(record_date) AS Year,
    MONTH(record_date) AS Month,
    COUNT(*) AS new
  FROM worktimes
  GROUP BY YEAR(record_date), MONTH(record_date)
 ) AS tmp;
```

Comment: Something is wrong because 'new' is the same as 'total' for the each row.

Comment: sorry forgot that it dosn't work well whit group by, rewriting it